# Argument of type "ULONG64 *" is incompatible with parameter of type "PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION"

Tags: c++, c

I'm new to C++ kernel structs. My ULONG code doesnt convert. My code, It gaves me error of bottom of the page. I tried convert to ULONG64 but nothing works. I may be missing a simple mistake as I haven't worked on a project like this before. But I couldn't understand why my project couldn't convert. Could you correct my code and tell me where I made the mistake? This kind of information really helps me learn.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_BIGPOOL_ENTRY {
    union {
        PVOID VirtualAddress;
        ULONG_PTR NonPaged : 1;
    };
    ULONG_PTR SizeInBytes;
    union {
        UCHAR Tag[4];
        ULONG64 TagULong;
    };
} SYSTEM_BIGPOOL_ENTRY, * PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_ENTRY;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION {
    ULONG64 Count;
    SYSTEM_BIGPOOL_ENTRY AllocatedInfo[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
} SYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION, * PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION;

typedef enum _SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    SystemBigPoolInformation
} SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS;
typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* fNtQuerySystemInformation)(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass, PVOID SystemInformation,
    ULONG64 SystemInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength);
NTSTATUS
ZwQuerySystemInformation(
    ULONG64 SystemInformationClass,
    PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION SystemInformation,
    ULONG64 SystemInformationLength,
    ULONG64* ReturnLength);
```

```
PVOID ExPool() {

    ULONG64 infoLen = 0;
    NTSTATUS status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemBigPoolInformation, &infoLen, 0, &infoLen);
    PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION pPoolInfo = 0;

    while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
    {
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Length : %lX", infoLen);

        if (pPoolInfo)
            ExFreePool(pPoolInfo);

        pPoolInfo = (PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION)ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, infoLen);
        status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemBigPoolInformation, pPoolInfo, infoLen, &infoLen);
    }

    if (pPoolInfo)
    {
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "status : %lX", status);
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Count : %lu", pPoolInfo->Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < pPoolInfo->Count; i++)
        {
            SYSTEM_BIGPOOL_ENTRY* Entry = &pPoolInfo->AllocatedInfo[i];
            PVOID VirtualAddress = (PVOID)((uintptr_t)Entry->VirtualAddress & ~1ull);
            SIZE_T SizeInBytes = Entry->SizeInBytes;
            BOOLEAN NonPaged = Entry->NonPaged;

            if (NonPaged && SizeInBytes == 0x200000)
            {
                DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "NonPagedPool : %p - %p", VirtualAddress, SizeInBytes);
            }
        }

        ExFreePool(pPoolInfo);

    }
}
```

````
argument of type "ULONG64 *" is incompatible with parameter of type "PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION" 

'NTSTATUS ZwQuerySystemInformation(ULONG64,PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION,ULONG64,ULONG64 *)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'ULONG64' to 'PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION'```
````

Comment: In your first call to `ZwQuerySystemInformation` you are passing `&infoLen`, which is pointer to `ULONG64`, as the 2nd parameter when it requires a `PSYSTEM_BIGPOOL_INFORMATION`.

Comment: @jkb how can i fix then? I'm really confused.

Comment: A simple cast will fix the compilation error. However, one thing that everyone needs to learn when it comes to either C or C++ (and by the way, you should figure out which language you're actually compiling, C and C++ are two completely different languages) is that just because a program compiles it does not guarantee that it will work correctly. So, although a simple cast  might fix the compilation error, the resulting code will be completely broken because the real problem is not the cast, but whichever logical problem resulted in the wrong type being passed to the function.

Comment: Hey @SamVarshavchik I don't fully understand the logic error here. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because in order to understand the logical error one needs to understand what the entire program is doing, and only you have the complete contents of the entire program. It sounds like it would be, perhaps, more productive to spend some time brushing up on the basics of C++ in order to attempt to work with what looks like advanced, low-level operating system library? Did you write all of the shown code? Give the complexity of the shown code, it seems to be something that a highly-experienced C or C++ developer would work with.

Comment: FIrst of all, you are using an undocumented structure with `ZwQuerySystemInformation`. I suggest you closely read the documentation for `ZwQuerySystemInformation`, especially the part that says this is no longer available for Windows 8 and up. For the structures that are documented, there are alternative functions that should be called instead.

Comment: @xfly4403 Your declaration of [`ZwQuerySystemInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/zwquerysysteminformation) is all wrong. It needs to match [`fNtQuerySystemInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation) (which is also wrong). Please read their documentations.